# Element is not allowed here: for qualifier in spring bean definition in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, javabeans, autowired

This is the file, I am trying examples from:
http://simplespringtutorial.com/annotations.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="foo" class="annotation.Foo">
    <property name="name" value="Daniel"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="anotherFoo" class="annotation.Foo">
   <qualifier value="secondaryFoo"></qualifier>
    <property name="name" value="Shirley"></property>

</bean>
<bean id="bar" class="annotation.Bar" />
</beans>
```

This is the Bar class
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

```
public class Bar {
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="anotherFoo")
private Foo foo;

@Resource(name="foo")
private Foo foo2;

public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
public void  printFooName(){
    System.out.println(foo.getName());
 //   System.out.println(foo2.getName());
}
}
```

This is the test bar which loads the xml file

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestFooBar {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "test2.xml");
    Bar bar = applicationContext.getBean("bar", Bar.class);
    bar.printFooName();
    System.out.println(bar.toString());
    /*
     * if a single definition of a class type exists, then u can get the
     * instance by this way also. No need to specify Id
     */
    Foo foo = applicationContext.getBean(Foo.class);
    System.out.println(foo.getName());
}

}
```

When I ran the application, the following is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bar': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private annotation.Foo annotation.Bar.foo; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [annotation.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=anotherFoo)}
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at annotation.TestFooBar.main(TestFooBar.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private annotation.Foo annotation.Bar.foo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [annotation.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=anotherFoo)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [annotation.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=anotherFoo)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
... 20 more
```

Comment: What Spring version are you on? Do you get this when loading the context or just a warning from Intellij editor?

Comment: I think that's spring version 3.0. It has problem to load in context,Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [annotation.Foo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:

Comment: Post the full stack trace, that is unrelated to the warning you are getting.

Comment: Add the `Bar` class too while you are at it.

Comment: And show us how you load the context.

Comment: Just added two classes, Bar and testBar, which loads the xml context file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the extra details, it wasn't immediately obvious what you were trying to do.

The `@Qualifier` annotation is not meant to be used in the same way as `@Resource`. When you specify the meta-data `<qualifier>` element, you are overwriting the identifier that would be used when resolving `@Qualifier`. In this case, the `<qualifier>` identifier `"secondaryFoo"` replaces the `<bean>` identifier `"anotherFoo"`. If you changed your declaration to

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "secondaryFoo")
private Foo foo;
```

It would be autowired correctly. However, you can still use

```
Foo anotherFoo = (Foo) applicationContext.getBean("anotherFoo");
```

to get the `<bean>` with `id` `"anotherFoo"`. Although this would fail

```
Foo anotherFoo = (Foo) applicationContext.getBean("secondaryFoo");
```

If you are looking for how to autowire based on a unique id, you should use `@Resource`. The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) states:

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not
>   primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of referring
>   to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, use the JSR-250
>   @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a
>   specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type
>   being irrelevant for the matching process.

Comment: I am just trying to following the tutorial and try the sample. I tried to change it to   @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="secondaryFoo")
    private Foo foo;

Comment: I am still seeing: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [annotation.Foo] is defined: expected single bean but found 2: foo,anotherFoo

Comment: @blue but that is expected, see the comments in your code. You have two beans of type Foo so the context doesn't know which one to give you

Comment: Will Qualifier keyword to distinguish two objects?

Comment: @Blue Please rephrase that. Use `@Resource` if you want to distinguish beans by unique identifier, use `@Qualifier` if you want a collection of beans of the same type having some qualifier value.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. What I am trying to do is to specify two beans with the same class name, one with qualifier, one without. To try the function of qualifier. But seems not working, I commented the @Resource annotation, still got the unique bean error during load. So I believe spring xml just don't like two bean with the same class at all, then I am wondering what's the purpose of qualier. Thanks.

Comment: @BlueDolphin Your code is failing on `applicationContext.getBean(Foo.class);`, which is expected because you are searching by type and there are two beans of that type, so Spring doesn't know which to give you. This has nothing to do with your `@Qualifier` and `@Resource` annotations in your `Bar` class. `@Qualifier` is just a way to narrow down the search. Read the linked documentation for additional details.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I should have check the stacktrace. Thanks!